# Updated to Xcode 4.6 and having weird XiB issues

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

updated to Xcode 4.6 today and opened up one of my projects and was greated with this lovely error.

*Interface Builder XiB Compiler Error.
Interface Builder could not open the document "ViewController_iPhone.xib" because it does not exist.*

Navigating to MyProject/en.lproj I still see the ViewController_iPhone.xib file. The last I used this project was last thursday night under xcode 4.5 and I built and distributed the project and 100% know the project was okay then. I have since gone back and accessed 3 different backups of the project and all 3 are giving me the same issue.

Now, this is where it gets even weirder. If I open the ViewController_iPhone.xib file by itself with xcode the view interface builder pops up is about an 4 month old version of my .xib, however I went and opened up a ~8 month old backup from when the project was a WIP and it loads the most recent XiB.

I've deleted the ViewController_iPhone.xib reference from Xcode and manually added it back in however the app terminates upon running with "could not load NIB in bundle" error and if I close and re open the project Xcode has lost my .xib again.

Little bit more to add, before hitting the Post your question button I thought I'd give ti one more try and copy and pasted a fresh copy of a backup ontop my desktop and opened it up and it exactly how it was suppose to be! But then I decided to close and reopen the same project and it's giving me the same the file doesn't exist error!

More info:
Mac OSX 10.8.2
Xcode: 4.6 (4H127)

I'm really lost as to what could be going on here and how to fix it. I've tried searching for people having similar issues and I couldn't find anybody else who's had this problem.

Thanks

Comment: mine is having a little trouble too! For some reason the new updated objects in the object library aren't showing up, and instead it is still showing the same objects as before @TyloBedo

Comment: I ran into a similar problem today, I tried to copy a xib and drag the copy into my project. Somehow I ended up with the same error. I tried deleting it and adding a new one by hand and that made it worse. I ended up doing a "git reset HEAD" on the file to unstage it, then added it again as a new file. Then I set the Location in the File Inspector to "relative to project" although I am not sure which of those was as the root of the problem. I suspect that XCode is doing some git inspection behind the scenes as it seems to show staged files that were deleted. Confusing and opaque!